# Creating an index score

Tags: statistics

I have a set of ranking that goes from 1 to 32844, I want to create an index where rank 1 = 1 and 32844 = 0 and 16422 = 0.5 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{rank}(n)= 1-\frac {n-1}{32843}.$$
But $16422$ is not exactly in the middle between $1$ and $32844$, so it will yield $\approx0.500015$ (instead of $0.5$) if we want to use linear functions.

Comment: I was doing it over 32844, tx